# ngBindHtml ignores text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue where using ngBindHtml brings up an issue.

If a user has entered the follow text `<somestring>`, ng-bind-html on the span tag only displays "".

It works fine on proper formatted html strings (eg. `<strong>somestring</strong> )`

Comment: can you create fiddle please?

Comment: That's because <somestring> is a dom element.

Comment: <somestring> will not be shown because it is an incomplete html tag